# Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. in google.com and youtube.com for edge

Tags: ssl, browser, ssl-certificate, certificate, microsoft-edge

I get this error `Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated` in my browser console whenever i open google.com or youtube.com... I think it has something to do with my ssl certificate however I've tried opening the urls in firefox and it seems to work just fine.

I've tried the following already:

> 1. Clearing certificate cache in internet options
> 2. Unchecking "Check for publisher's and server certificate revocation in internet options advanced properties
> 3. Clearing cookies and site data
> 4. Disabling my extensions
> 5. Reseting my edge browser
> 6. Uninstalling and Reinstalling my edge browser
> 7. tried in incognito mode

Comment: The error is most likely connected with network problems. Are you using the proxy server on Firefox to successfully land on these pages? If so, it is also required in Edge. You can also check if you unintentionally switch to **Offline** in throttling dropdown list of Network panel in Edge dev tools. If so, you should switch to **No throttling**. If it doesn't work, I suggest taking screenshots of the page and the browser console, so that I can have a better understanding of the issue.